# Mysql: WHERE not working in subquery?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the WHERE part of my subquery to work below. I can see that 'where event_id=..' is ambiguous because the parent query is looking at the same table.

Is it even possible to have a WHERE in a same-table subquery?

```
UPDATE tickets SET tickets.ticket_number = ( 
    SELECT max_ticket 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT (MAX(ticket_number)+1) AS max_ticket 
        FROM tickets 
        WHERE event_id=10045
    )
    AS sub_table
) 
WHERE ticket_id=68
```

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting deja vu all over again. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'd say this is a pretty straight forward question. Sometimes including lots of extraneous info can make things harder to understand..

Comment: I disagree. But it seems I'm in the minority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly try it as a join

```
UPDATE tickets a
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT (MAX(ticket_number)+1) AS max_ticket 
    FROM tickets 
    WHERE event_id = 10045
) b
SET a.ticket_number = b.max_ticket
WHERE a.ticket_id = 68
```